# Edit a Part title page. Book document

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, parts

Could anyone give me some help with editing a \part title page? When introducing a part a whole page is reserved for the name of this part before the rest of text in it, and I would like to add some figures or extra details to this page. I am working on a book document type.

Thank you in advance!

Alvaro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) then it has a macro `\partpageend` which is effectively called after the `\part` title macro to finish off the part page. By default this gives the same part page output as the `book` class does. You can change the `\partpageend` macro to enable things to be put after the part title and on the same page.

```
% partpageptob.tex SE 644223

\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\partpageend}{}

\begin{document}

\part{A PART}

Possibly some text on the PART page (depending on the definition of
\verb|\partpageend|).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Read the `memoir` manual for much more information on this.

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I will take a look at the manual, I am hoping to add some logos on the page.